# Update macro values when cell value changes

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, macros

I have a checkbox control with a macro that takes value from cell 6 columns over and inserts it in either the 8th or 9th column over depending on whether the checkbox is checked or unchecked. This is the macro:

```
Public Sub CB_Read()

Dim oShape As Shape
Dim oTarget As Range
Dim iTarget As Range

Set oShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)
'Change the "Offset(Row,Column)" in the next line to whatever cell is desired for the status of the checkbox.
Set StdRate = oShape.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 6)
Set oTarget = oShape.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 8)
Set iTarget = oShape.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, 9)


If oShape.ControlFormat.Value = xlOff Then
    iTarget.Value = StdRate.Value * [cityIndex]
    oTarget.Value = ""
Else
    oTarget.Value = StdRate.Value * [cityIndex]

    iTarget.Value = ""
End If

End Sub
```

**I'd now like the values in the offset columns (iTarget.Value and oTarget.Value) to update when value in cell named [cityIndex] is changed, without having to operate the checkbox.**

Comment: Have you tried writing a function for the event `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`?

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a VBA function that looked at the value of the cityindex cell and changed the offset accordingly.

Exactly how to do this depends on what you put in the cityindex cell. If it is a number then you can probably simply add that number to the base offset to get the right column. If it is text, you will need to do a lookup - if the cities don't change much, it is probably easiest to do that right in the code, otherwise you will need a lookup table in a worksheet and will need to do a vlookup on it.